# Select * From 'table' not working php

Tags: php, mysql, database

MY mysql_query`("Select * From 'Table'")` isn't working in PHP.

I get an error

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
 (using password: NO)
```

. The weird thing is that all `my INSERT INTO PHP` code works without a problem.

Any help?!

**UPDATE**

The server doesn't work with any `SELECT *` statements but works with `INSERT INTO` statements. I am using an Amazon EC2 Windows Instances with Bitnami WAMP.

```
<?php
$servername = "server";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());

$conn->close();
?>
```

This gets the error.

It's not my connection though because I do the exact same code for `INSERT INTO` statement and it works. It might be a config error..

Comment: For those people looking at this question in 2015, mysql_query is deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli

Comment: @fandressouza for some reason the server doesn't work with mysqli_query

Comment: Set user credentials on `mysql` server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap off quotes in Table. Table is [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) in mysql it must be in backtick

```
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `table`")) {
         printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
         $result->close();
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

Comment: Yes I tried but no work. Seems like the server is not working on any SELECT * statements but works with INSERT INTO statements.

Comment: how do you print what is retrieved from the query?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `''` Try this code like that :-

```
mysql_query("Select * From Table ")
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't get rid of the error @Rahautos

Comment: check your connection setting like user or password is correct or not @user5432778

Comment: yeah my user or password is correct because I am using a connect file that has all my connection stuff in it and I use it in different php files

Comment: no my code is not working. I said the connect is working. I just posted my code

Answer (score 0):

There isn't mysql database connection on that query so you get that kind of message

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * FROM  table") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($result  as $result )
{
  echo $result['id'];
     // Another code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows for granulated permissions, so it's possible to allow a user to INSERT but not SELECT. You can use the GRANT command to add the SELECT permission, e.g

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Answer (score -1):

```
try using this in your connection.php:
      `$host = 'your_host';
      $user = 'your_user';
      $pass = 'your_pass';

      $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

      if($connect){
          echo "the connection was success";
      }else{
          echo "the coonection failed because".mysql_error();
      }`
```